# Amazon S3 storage pricing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

If I use Amazon s3 storage services to host my pictures and download-able content how much should I paid. I need to know how much do you paid for your projects? And how cheap s3 is?

I need to figure out pricing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/

http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/calc5.html

Comment: +1 for the calculator utility. I was unaware.

Answer (score 0):

Look there http://aws.amazon.com/s3/ scroll down and select your region.

For US it is:

```
>   Standard Storage    Reduced Redundancy Storage First 1 TB / month   $0.125
> per GB    $0.093 per GB Next 49 TB / month    $0.110 per GB   $0.083 per GB
> Next 450 TB / month   $0.095 per GB   $0.073 per GB Next 500 TB /
> month $0.090 per GB   $0.063 per GB Next 4000 TB / month  $0.080 per
> GB    $0.053 per GB Over 5000 TB / month  $0.055 per GB   $0.037 per GB
```